# React Route shows up a blank page

Tags: reactjs, routes, mern

I am creating a MERN project in webstorm. I am trying to direct to another React component upon clicking a button in one React component. I did that using Routes. Redirection happens. But the content in my second React component is not showing up.

```
            <Button block bsSize="large" disabled={!validateForm()} type="submit">
                {/* eslint-disable-next-line no-undef */}
                <Route path = "./" component = {AppointmentMakingComponent} />
            </Button>
```

My second React component is

```
    import React from 'react'

    class Hello extends React.Component {

          constructor(props){

               //Since we are extending the default constructor,
               //handle default activities first.
               super(props);

               //Extract the first-name from the prop
               let firstName = "abc"

               //In the constructor, feel free to modify the
               //state property on the current context.
               this.state = {
                    name: firstName
               }

           } //Look maa, no comma required in JSX based class defs!

           render() {
                return <h1>Hello, {this.state.name}!</h1>
           }
    }

    export default Hello
```

Please help

Comment: @Prasadike please add `AppointmentMakingComponent ` and path name

Comment: Also kindly scrutinize this line `<Route path="./" component= AppointmentMakingComponent} />`, perhaps removing that "dot" from the path might help.